# Beginner question about generics

Tags: vb.net, generics

Are these two statments equivalent?

```
Public Class Class2(Of X As Class1)
Public Class Class2(Of X As {Class1})
```

What does the "New" mean?

```
Public Class Class2(Of X As {Class1, New})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first two statements are equivalent. The curly brackets are how to use multiple generic constraints in VB.NET. In your case even though there are brackets, there is only a single constraint.

The `New` keyword is a constraint that ensures the type `T` has a constructor that takes no parameters. So your second definition ensures that `T` is or inherits from `Class1` and has parameterless constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Could I create a constraint to require a constructor with a different signature? For example Public Class Class2(Of X As {Class1, New(y as integer)}). I get an error with this....

Comment: @Velika - No. That's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Read these links:

- [Class Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa0hwf23%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Type List Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4xaz66w%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [New Keyword Explanantion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)